# Create a GET request to Coinbase with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, coinbase-api

I have very basic knowledge in JS and C#, and now I'm trying to build my first web app with JS. I want to create a web app which creates a GET request to Coinbase website and takes the current price of Bitcoin, Ethereum and etc. and show it in my web app.
Can you provide me a website where i can start with?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coinbase has a [maintained API](https://developers.coinbase.com/) you can use to fetch the data you need. They support [various solutions](https://docs.gdax.com/#sandbox) (REST, Websocket, etc.), depending on your requirements.

Resources for getting started with general web development is an entirely different beast. I would suggest Angular's [Heroes Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial), and from there read up on [AJAX](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_ajax.htm) or Websockets (for the latter, I suggest [socket.io](https://socket.io/)).

Expect 100-250 hours work.